# Bash: combining of the composition of the multiple log files based on the search pattern

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, logs

I have a folder with many of the txt files. Where each of the file is present in the following format:

```
Allowed overlap: -3
H-bond overlap reduction: 0.4
Ignore contacts between atoms separated by 4 bonds or less
Detect intra-residue contacts: False
Detect intra-molecule contacts: False

19 contacts
atom1  atom2  overlap  distance
:128.B@BB  :300.C@BB  -1.676  4.996
:179.B@BB  :17.C@BB   -1.898  5.218
:182.B@BB  :17.C@BB   -2.015  5.335
```

My aim: is to loop the files within the folder and combine them together within the one global output. Notable in the example, I want to consider only the strings after (and including it) the "19 (this number is different in each of the file) contacts" , thus skipping the first six lines of the file.

Possible work-flow for the realization:

```
# make a log file which will contain info from all files going to be looped on the next step.
echo "This is a beginning of the global output" > ./final_output.txt
# that is a key phrase which is the indicator of the first string which should be taken from each of the files
key= "#any of the digit# contacts" 

#now I want to loop each of the files with the aim to add all of the strings after (and including) ${key} to the final_output.txt
for file in ${folder}/*.txt; do
  file_title=$(basename "$file")
  # 1- print the ${file_title} within the final_output.txt
  # 2 -  add all of the strings from the file into the final_output.txt
  # NB ! I need to take only the strings after (and including) the key-phrace

done
```

Comment: If you are sure there are always 6 lines at beginning to remove, `tail -n +6` would do the trick

Comment: i want more complex general sollution to do the search againt the keyword. BTW what command can add the name of the lopped file to the beggining of the big log ?

Answer (score 0):

Taken the example of 3 files

file1

```
Allowed overlap: -3
H-bond overlap reduction: 0.4
Ignore contacts between atoms separated by 4 bonds or less
Detect intra-residue contacts: False
Detect intra-molecule contacts: False

19 contacts
atom1  atom2  overlap  distance
:128.B@BB  :300.C@BB  -1.676  4.996
:179.B@BB  :17.C@BB   -1.898  5.218
:182.B@BB  :17.C@BB   -2.015  5.335
```

---

file3

```
Allowed overlap: -3
H-bond overlap reduction: 0.4
Ignore contacts between atoms separated by 4 bonds or less
Detect intra-residue contacts: False
Detect intra-molecule contacts: False

17 contacts
atom1  atom2  overlap  distance
:128.B@BB  :300.C@BB  -1.676  4.996
:179.B@BB  :17.C@BB   -1.898  5.218
:182.B@BB  :17.C@BB   -2.015  5.335
```

---

file4

```
Allowed overlap: -3
H-bond overlap reduction: 0.4
Ignore contacts between atoms separated by 4 bonds or less
Detect intra-residue contacts: False
Detect intra-molecule contacts: False

12 contacts
atom1  atom2  overlap  distance
:128.B@BB  :300.C@BB  -1.676  4.996
:179.B@BB  :17.C@BB   -1.898  5.218
:182.B@BB  :17.C@BB   -2.015  5.335
```

---

Below is code which will save the output from 19contacts,17contacts,12 contacts till the end of file

```
 for i in file1 file3 file4; do sed -n '/^[0-9]/,$p'  $i; done > /var/tmp/outputfile.txt
```

output

```
19 contacts
atom1  atom2  overlap  distance
:128.B@BB  :300.C@BB  -1.676  4.996
:179.B@BB  :17.C@BB   -1.898  5.218
:182.B@BB  :17.C@BB   -2.015  5.335
17 contacts
atom1  atom2  overlap  distance
:128.B@BB  :300.C@BB  -1.676  4.996
:179.B@BB  :17.C@BB   -1.898  5.218
:182.B@BB  :17.C@BB   -2.015  5.335
12 contacts
atom1  atom2  overlap  distance
:128.B@BB  :300.C@BB  -1.676  4.996
:179.B@BB  :17.C@BB   -1.898  5.218
:182.B@BB  :17.C@BB   -2.015  5.335
```

Comment: Thank you it works very good! Here the expression for SED is looking exactly for the pattern like "digit contacts", does not it? One question: is it possible to add near the begining of each entity the name of the file from which it has been taken e.g:  19 contacts from file1 ?

Comment: Use below command to get the same                                                                                            for i in file1 file3 file4; do sed -n '/^[0-9]/,$p'   $i| head -1| awk -v  i="$i" '{print $0" " "from" " "  i}'  ; sed -n '/^[0-9]/,$p'   $i;done.                                                               it will print as example 19 contacts from file1

Comment: Kindly Vote for my answer

Comment: Thanks! is it possible that the script write not the path to the file at the end but rather the name of the file (w.o. its extension?) As I will reach 15 posts I will vote for your answer !!

Comment: OK No problem Will wait for your vote. Can You please explain your query clearly

Answer (score 0):

I Found another Method with the same input files

Code:

```
 for i in file1 file3 file4; do sed '1,6d'  $i; done > /var/tmp/outputfile.txt
```

Output

```
19 contacts
atom1  atom2  overlap  distance
:128.B@BB  :300.C@BB  -1.676  4.996
:179.B@BB  :17.C@BB   -1.898  5.218
:182.B@BB  :17.C@BB   -2.015  5.335
17 contacts
atom1  atom2  overlap  distance
:128.B@BB  :300.C@BB  -1.676  4.996
:179.B@BB  :17.C@BB   -1.898  5.218
:182.B@BB  :17.C@BB   -2.015  5.335
12 contacts
atom1  atom2  overlap  distance
:128.B@BB  :300.C@BB  -1.676  4.996
:179.B@BB  :17.C@BB   -1.898  5.218
:182.B@BB  :17.C@BB   -2.015  5.335
```

Comment: Thank you! One question: is it possible to add near the begining of each entity the name of the file from which it has been taken e.g:  19 contacts from file1 ?